# After an Ajax GET request to controller method that should return a redirect URL in JSON, I am getting a 500 error and not hitting the AJAX success

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The following is the AJAX caller:

```
function editItem(id) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/bookmarkrest/edititem?Id=' + id,
                success: function (json) {
                    //alert('Success.');
                    window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("No Change.");
                }
            });
        };
```

The following is the method called. The EditLink method should take me to a different page (the specified page):

```
      public ActionResult EditItem(int? Id = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Bookmark bookmark = repository.GetBookmark(Id);


            if (bookmark is Link)
            {
                return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("EditLink", "BookmarkREST", new { Id = Id }) });
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditLink(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Link link = repository.GetLink(id); 

        if (link == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(new LinkViewModel { name = link.Name, uri = link.URI });

    }
```

[image]

I am also getting the correct response in the Chrome Developer tool's Network request response tab:
[image]

If I type in the URL, I do access the correct page with data:
[image]

I'm not sure why I am kept on the same page, can somebody help?

Comment: Because the whole point of AJAX is to stay on the same page.  If you want to just go to the other page, what you want is a link.

Comment: Just use a regular anchor or you'll need to do the redirection yourself `window.location = url`

Comment: I've added 2 lines of code, one in ajax success, one in EditItem method to return JSON. I get a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax request had to be a POST and datatype attribute included:

```
function editItem(id) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                url: '/bookmarkrest/edititem?Id=' + id,
                success: function (json) {
                    //alert('Success.');
                    window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                },
                error: function (json) {
                    alert(json.message);
                }
            });
        };
```